# How to Make Auto Clicking For A Specified Link

Tags: php, hyperlink, click

i want a php code for automatically clicking on a Specified text or link on a page.

thanks

Comment: NO. Stackoverflow doesn't work that way. Heck, you're not everyone's boss. You don't come here asking people to write whole codes for you, for free, upon requirements. YOU write the code, and if you've problems or are stuck YOU show what YOU have done and we help finding mistakes. Please read the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) section

Answer (score 1):

You want to use JavaScript code.

Just insert a `script` tag just before the closing `body` tag on the web page. It should look something like this:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("#my-link").click();
</script>
```

That will click the link with the HTML ID "my-link".

Note that generally this is not a good idea to implement. If you need to forward the user to another page, you can do that without simulating a mouse click - in PHP you can use the code

```
header("Location: redirectToHere.php");
```

and that will redirect the user automatically. If you need to change things on the page, you can do that by directly setting their properties with JavaScript.